# Angular2 @ngFor directive and table generation with Dart

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

I have a single map

#### .dart

```
Map<String, String> name = {"title":"Countess","first":"Tommy","last":"Clarke","middle":"Kowan","suffix":"Junior"}
```

I would like to use angular2 @ngFor directive to construct a table looking like the one below
[image]

I can create the table in the conventional way using @ngFor with the Name column forming the table header row and the input column placed as the first table row. The graphic shown was done with the following code:

#### .html

```
<table class = "mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-tablemdl-shadow--4dp">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</th>
      <th>Input</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Title</td>
      <td>{{name.title}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">First</td>
      <td>{{name.first}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Middle</td>
      <td>{{name.middle}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Last</td>
      <td>{{name.last}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Suffix</td>
      <td>{{name.suffix}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I crate the table in the graphic using @ngFor directive?

### EDIT1 - CONSOLE ERROR WHEN RUN WITH FIRST SOLUTION

```
>EXCEPTION: Class '_CompactIterable' has no instance method '[]'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of '_CompactIterable'
Arguments: [null] in [{{names.keys[idx].slice(1,1).toUpperCase()}}{{names.keys[idx].slice(2)}} in NameComponent@148:52]
  EXCEPTION: Class '_CompactIterable' has no instance method '[]'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of '_CompactIterable'
Arguments: [null] in [{{names.keys[idx].slice(1,1).toUpperCase()}}{{names.keys[idx].slice(2)}} in NameComponent@148:52]
    (anonymous function)    
  ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Class '_CompactIterable' has no instance method '[]'.
```

### .dart (Dart's port of SnareChops answer below) | CORRECT ANSWER

Added a custom pipe to perform the capitalization

```
///Takes the first letter of [String] key in a [Map], capitalizes it and 
///returns the key value as the capitallized word
@Pipe( name: 'capitalize' )
class CapitalizePipe extends PipeTransform {
  dynamic transform( String value, List args ) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer( );

    List<String> list = value.split( '' );
    if ( value != null ) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
        if ( i == 0 ) {
          buffer.write( list[i].toUpperCase( ) );
          continue;
        }

        buffer.write( list[i] );
      }
    }
    return buffer.toString( );
  }
}

  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "#name of names?.keys">
    <td class = "mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{name | capitalize}}</td>
    <td>
      {{names[name]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Marking the post with the dart tag lets users know which language you are using angular2 with since it supports 3 different languages and each one has it's nuances.

Comment: @SnareChops Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the keys of the `Map`, use those for the titles, and then you can use the key to access the value in the `Map` which gives you the value.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="#name of names?.keys">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{names[name]}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please see console errors in formatted question above when the solution is attempted.

Comment: Terribly sorry that I'm not more knowledgeable of dart, this is valid JS and TS. How would one get a key by index using dart? Or perhaps it's `names.keys()[idx]...`?

Comment: Don't worry, the principle is correct. Please see the corrected Dart port in the question above. The $index is not needed in Dart for this case. I will have to find the slice() method in Dart to apply in though for the capitalization. If there is no equivalent, I will have to create a pipe that does the capitalization. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, that is a much better way to accomplish that, and also valid JS/TS. Would you like to post that as an answer since it does answer the question?

Comment: It is your idea SnareChops - replace your answer with the above and I will delete mine. That is fair, and the only thing to do. Visit [compariative methods of TS, JS and Dart](http://hyperpolyglot.org/web) to see the similar methods.

Comment: A peculiar thing occured though - it seems that the class is invisble - the data is as above, but the tabular borders are absent. I will have to investigate.

Comment: Let me add the equivalent of the slice() before you post the code - will do in a few minutes.

Comment: Trying to create a `capitalize` pipe but having some errors.

Comment: Please use the above solution in your answer. The Pipe was created to make reuse easier. Appreciate your effort to the max.